# Transfer everything to new phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, data-transfer

I am changing from one Galaxy S3 to another S3. How can I transfer ALL my stuff? (I am not rooted.)

Answer (score 8):

Your apps will be synchronized with your Google account. You can see what apps are synchronized by going to the web-based Google play/android market site and going into account settings.

Your contacts as well are synchronized by default but to make sure, go to account settings on your phone.

Your pictures, downloads, and any other files you may want to transfer can be uploaded to your computer temporarily and then from your computer to your new phone.

Alternatively, you could do this last bit a number of ways:

- Bluetooth: [Bluetooth File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.medieval.blueftp&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIml0Lm1lZGlldmFsLmJsdWVmdHAiXQ..)
- FTP: [FTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lutey.FTPServer&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImx1dGV5LkZUUFNlcnZlciJd), [FTP Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andftp&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImx5c2Vzb2Z0LmFuZGZ0cCJd)
- SAMBA: [SAMBA Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funkyfresh.samba&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5mdW5reWZyZXNoLnNhbWJhIl0.), [SAMBA Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lysesoft.andsmb&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwibHlzZXNvZnQuYW5kc21iIl0.)

You get the idea: [File Transfer Apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=file%20transfer&c=apps)

You would need to root your phone to be able to access or copy the application data to your new phone.

Comment: what about the data for he apps, logins, etc?

Comment: How an application stores its settings data is different so the task would not be simple to do manually. I believe Titanium Backup will do this, but you need to be rooted: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5rZXJhbWlkYXMuVGl0YW5pdW1CYWNrdXAiXQ..

Comment: There's really no better way than uploading everything and downloading it again?

Comment: In terms of media or other files, the below answer suggest DroidCopy as a way to easily do so over bluetooth. There are tons of direct phone-to-phone transfer applications that would make it simpler. I'll update the answer

Comment: I'm not concerned about the data such as pictures, voice files, etc. I can copy to SD Card, DropBox, etc. WHAT I am concerned about are all my apps and their specific data. When you say that google keeps a copy on Google Play - does this contain the data as well? (I know that not all apps have data but those that do.) And also I see all my apps on Google Play web site but how do I restore them to new phone? (BTW, both phones are Galaxy S3.)

Comment: Google does not store your application data, rather just that you have the application installed on your phone and synced with your gmail account. You would need to root your phone to be able to access or copy the application data to your new phone. After you synchronize your new phone to that same gmail account, the applications will be downloaded automatically. You can in fact synchronize your gmail account right now on your new phone if you currently have both phones in your possession and wait while it starts to grab the applications.

Comment: About Root -
1. do both phones need to be rooted or only the one from where I'm copying?
2. I have a Galaxy S3 T999 - can someone point me to instructions on how to Root or are there free apps that will do it

Comment: Yes I believe both need to be rooted, but if you can do one, you can do two. Your much more likely to get results by googling around rather than posing the question in comments.

Comment: To add to Enigma's post - you would need to make sure that you have set up the google backup option - from home screen: menu - settings - Back up and reset. Make sure Back up my data and automatic restore is ticked.

Answer (score 5):

There's an app that can do this, un-rooted, called [DroidCopy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vmad.droidcopy.server)

It transfers everything across via Bluetooth.

***Disclosure:*** I am associated with the app.

Comment: That seems like a great app. Does it also transfer application settings data. ie. Angry Birds completion status or login information?

Comment: no, those settings for applications require root, and have strived to keep it "free of any root mechanisms", it will of course transfer the APKs no problem, but settings etc will not be copied over for that reason :)

Comment: Where did that app go? The link seems gone. Or are there any "location based locks" in place? "Sorry! This content is not available in your country yet." (Playstore) versus "This app is currently not active on Google Play" (AppBrain).

Answer (score 3):

[Helium - App Sync and Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=en) (previously Carbon) will sync all your app data, such as settings and so on:

> Helium lets you backup your apps and data to your SD card or cloud
>   storage. With Helium, you can sync app data from your other Android
>   devices-- even if they are not on the same network [...] Helium does
>   NOT require root. All Android users can use Helium to backup and sync
>   Android applications.

Comment: Used it today to transfer game saves from an LG L7 to a Samsung Galaxy SIII Mini, by way of the "PC Download" feature. Worked perfectly, great app.