# Transfer apps, data, and settings from Marshmallow to Lollipop

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, data-transfer

I've been using a Moto E 2nd generation that I bought in Europe, but I've now returned to the US and am replacing it with the US version (XT1527) of the same phone because the European one (XT1524) doesn't get LTE service with my carrier, AT&T.

The old phone is running Android 6.0, but the new one only has Android 5.1, and offered me no options whatsoever to transfer anything over when I set it up.

I'm no Android expert, so forgive me if the answer should be obvious, but…what's the best way for me to get my apps, app data, and settings transferred across to the new phone?

I sort of thought Android was supposed to offer to do this for me at setup, but maybe it doesn't work when moving to an older version of the OS?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Related and strongly recommended to check: [Transfer everything to new phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/29669/16575) and [Is it possible to migrate apps and their data from one unrooted Android phone to another?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/88563/16575) Both predate Marshmallow and thus should apply. Also see: our [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info), especially for [adb backups](//android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backup+adb). [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296/16575) is worth a look, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pc and patience you can transfer all things from your old Android smartphone to new one.
For contacts 
Transfer your contacts from phone to your gmail ID(add a account then press sync contact in account section..Google it if u don't know)
For photos
Normally photos are stored in

> Internal/DCIM
>   Copy it into your pc

For apps 
Download a app called App Backup Restore - transfer
And backup all your apps and transfer it to your pc 
For game/app data 
Its usually stored at internal /Android
Here you will find 2 folders one is data and other one is obb
Data contain all the data's of apps and small games
Obb contain files of large games

Or

You can use Xender or ShareIt to transfer all files from old Android to your new Android phone.
Hope I help you