# How to Restore notepad.db in Huawei P7 without factory reset

Tags: restore, file-transfer, huawei, huawei-ascend-p7

kindly advise the following.

I have 2 huawei p7 phones, but only 1 sim card(used by the main phone ), and need transfer all the Notepad files to new phone.

- The Main one :
  although no problem access to internet, but unable to download any apps from Google Playstore, due to certain part of its mobile data reception ability got affected after the phone suffered too many times of hard hit previously.

Its android Beam NFC function also not working.

- The secondary(new) one :
  ready to replace the main phone, can download apps no problem.
  But there are existing notes and other photo files in it.

.
I have backed up the notepad in the Main phone using the Backup function in huawei p7. The backup file is a zip file.
.
So my dilemma now is :
- How to Restore notepad.db in the new Huawei P7 above, without factory reset ?

- I am trying to restore all the Notepad from the Main phone into the Secondary new phone, without affecting the existing notepad files in the new phone.
- Is there anyway to copy the backup file Notepad.db to a path in the new huawei p7 in order to let the note files restored automatically ?

I only have these 2 mobile phones for any file transfer. No pc or laptop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give it a look [1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29669/transfer-everything-to-new-phone) & [2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88563/is-it-possible-to-migrate-apps-and-their-data-from-one-unrooted-android-phone-to).  You might extract something useful.

Comment: I'd second "2" and Helium. Or, as "main" cannot download any apps: Do you have a computer you could use with [adb](/tags/adb/info)? In that case, the easiest approach would be performing an `adb backup -apk -f <com.app.notepad>.apk <com.app.notepad>` with "main" connected, followed by `adb restore <com.app.notepad>.ab` with "new" connected. In both cases, replace `<com.app.notepad>` with the package name of your notepad app. And omit the `-apk` if it is an app that already ships pre-installed with your device.